# Highschool Exam Question About Cube Factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Given;
$ a^3 - 3ab^2 = 10 $ and $  b^3 - 3ba^2 = 5$

What is the value of $ a^2 + b^2  $ ?

Comment: I have tried adding and substracting both equations and try to get a^2 + b^2. I couldn't progress at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(a+bi)^3=(a^3-3a^2b)-i(b^3-3a^2b)=10-5i$$

$$a^2+b^2=|a+bi|^2$$

Comment: I dont know complex numbers to that extent. The right answer is a real number ( actually it is 5) and i cant see how i will get that.

Comment: Take norms on both sides.

Comment: Then $$(a^3-3ab^2)^2+(b^3-3a^2b)^2=(a^2+b^2)^3.$$

Comment: @Coincidence Similarly $(a-bi)^3 = 10+5i$, and $(a-bi)^3(a+bi)^3 = (a^2+b^2)^3$.

Comment: Oh my bad i didn't saw it was that easy. Thank you both.

Answer (score 12):

\begin{align}
    10 &= a^3 - 3ab^2 \\
    5 &= b^3 - 3a^2b \\
    \hline
    100 &= a^6 -6a^4b^2 + 9a^2b^4 \\
    25 &= b^6 - 6a^2b^4 + 9a^4b^2 \\
    \hline
    125 &= a^6 + 3a^4b^2 + 3a^2b^4 + b^6 \\
    5^3 &= (a^2 + b^2)^3 \\
    5 &= a^2 + b^2
\end{align}